# Remove the stack bars

Tags: mplfinance

```py
ap = [ mpf.make_addplot(df['VWAP'], color='blue', width=0.8,
                        panel=0, ylabel='VWAP ($)'),
       mpf.make_addplot(df['volume'], type='bar', color='dimgray',
                        width=0.8, panel=1, ylabel='Volume',
                        secondary_y=False)]

mpf.plot(df, type='candle', style="yahoo", volume=True,
         addplot=ap, title=args.ticker, 
         ylabel='Price ($)', ylabel_lower='Shares\nTraded')
```

[image]

As you can see on the plot, there is two stack volume bars, i.e. a red or green bar and a grey bar over it. How can I remove the grey bar?

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the grey bars there *yourself* with

```py
mpf.make_addplot(df['volume'], type='bar', color='dimgray',
                        width=0.8, panel=1, ylabel='Volume',
                        secondary_y=False)]
```

Just remove that `make_addplot` call, and you will remove the grey bar!

Comment: I need both plots. The vwap is the blue line with the OLHC candles on top and the volume is the bar below. I need both of them.

Comment: So, do you want to get rid of the red/green volumes, and keep the grey volumes?   Or you want both volume plots but just not on top of each other?   *They are the same data.*  I don't understand why you would want both volume plots.  Pick the one you want.  The red/green one comes from the `volume=True` kwarg.

Comment: No, I would like to get rid of the grey volume bars and get rid of the grey one

Comment: So, you have your answer:  
- Remove the `mpf.make_addplot(df['volume']...` 
- (but keep `mpf.make_addplot(df['VWAP'],`)